# How Ransack can search for Rails6 Action Text content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I've upgraded my project to Rails6 (v6.0.1) and now using Action Text in my model. However I cannot find a way to change my Ransack to be able to search text from the content, which I understand that after Action Text migration it is now stored within attribute `body` of table `action_text_rich_texts`. Would anyone have a good suggestion?

Error message:

```
undefined method `content_body_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: Topic, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search
```

Below is the extract of my code.

Model:

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :content
```

Controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Topic.ransack(params[:q])
    @topics = @search.result
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= search_form_for(@search, url: topics_path, html: {method: :get, role: 'form'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content_body_cont %>
```

Schema file:

```
create_table "action_text_rich_texts", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "body", size: :long
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name"], name: "index_action_text_rich_texts_uniqueness", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= text_field_tag "topic[content_body_cont]" %>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.